# High Chart change gauge needle to a triangle

Tags: highcharts

I want to create a semi circle that contains a gauge embedded in it.

Example:[Semi Circle Pie With Gauge](http://jsfiddle.net/ymf2zzn1/1/)

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2015',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 40
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '75%'],
            size: '50%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'none',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 90,
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
            tickWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: '', //'<div class="gaugeFooter">46% Rate</div>',
                useHTML: true,
                y: 80
            },
            /*plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 46,
                color: 'pink',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                outerRadius: '0%'
            },{
                from: 46,
                to: 90,
                color: 'tan',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                outerRadius: '0%'
            }],*/
            pane: 0,

        }],
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: -50,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white',
                        textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
                    }
                },
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                center: ['50%', '75%']
            },
            gauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dial: {
                    radius: '100%'
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   25],
                ['IE',       25],
                ['Chrome', 25],
                ['Opera',     25]
            ]
        },{
            type: 'gauge',
            data: [40],
            dial: {
                rearLength: 0
            }
        }],
    });    
});
```

I want to change the needle to become a pure css triangle.

Is there a way todo this?

Comment: The link to the fiddle is:  http://jsfiddle.net/ymf2zzn1/1/

Comment: So you would like to get something similar to this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ymf2zzn1/34/

Comment: Similar yes. I am waiting on product people to agree that this works. If they say no, then I need to use a triangle instead of the speedometer gauge.

Comment: see the following question with attached image.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722989/highchart-how-do-i-create-the-attached-image-gauge-within-a-semicircle-pie-cha

Answer (score 0):

edit the dial according to your measure, the below object will also give an triangle
dial: {
radius: '4%',
backgroundColor: 'black',
baseWidth: 12,
baseLength: '7%',
rearLength: '5%'
},